# Unamanged memory struct

Tags: c#

i'm pretty confused.

I've these structs.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, Size = 4 + 64 * 3)]
public struct MapBlock
{
    public readonly uint Header;
    public unsafe MapCells* Cells;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct MapCells
{
    public ushort TileID;
    public sbyte Z;
}
```

the "MapCells" param into MapBlock is an array of 64 MapCells.

I've to access to a specific index of a mapcell and to do this i'm doing:

```
 MapBlock* mp = (MapBlock*) blockIndex.MapAddress;
 MapCells* cells = (MapCells*) &mp->Cells;
 var z = cells[my * 8 + mx].Z;
```

That's works.
Why if i try to do this, it doesnt work?

```
MapBlock* mp = (MapBlock*) blockIndex.MapAddress;
MapCells* cells = &mp->Cells[0];
var z = cells[my * 8 + mx].Z;
```

I don't want use marshalling.

EDIT:
Error message: memory access violation

Comment: Please always include error messages so that we aren't forced to guess what is not working for your case

Comment: @Vroomfondel added, thanks

Comment: It is an array. So try this : MapCells* cells = mp->Cells;

Comment: @jdweng Access violation exception.

Comment: Who knows what's wrong given so little detail.